# Ratio of holomorphic forms on a Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $R$ be a Riemann surface of genus $g>1$ and $\omega$, $\sigma$ two holomorphic 1-forms on $R$. This means that locally we can write $\omega=fdz$ and $\sigma=gdz$ with $f$ and $g$ holomorphic. Now suppose that the forms $\omega$ and $\sigma$ have just one zero of multiplicity $2g-2$ in the same point.

From $\omega$ and $\sigma$ we get a well defined function $\theta:R\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which locally is defined as $\frac f g$.

My question is: **is $\theta$ a holomorphic function?**

I think yes, because $f$ and $g$ have a zero of the same multiplicity in the same point, so $\theta$ should have no poles.. but then this means that $\theta$ should be a constant function.. So this implies that every two holomorphic 1-forms on $R$ with one zero of multiplicity $2g-2$ in the same point differ by a constant? This doesn't seem right because this would mean that the complex vector space of holomorphic forms with one zero of multiplicity $2g-2$ in a fixed point should have dimension 1 which is impossible.. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct and your argument is correct. (One can also think about this in terms of linear systems.  If $D$ is a divisor of degree $0$, then $h^0(D)\le 1$, with equality holding precisely when $D$ is the trivial divisor.)

Comment: Thank you! but then there is something else I don't understand.. Call $P\in R$ the point where the forms $\omega$ and $\sigma$ have the zero. The relative cohomology  group $H^1(R,P,\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $H^1(R,\mathbb{C})$ which has complex dimension $2g$. Every element $\psi\in H^1(R,P,\mathbb{C})$ is a complex 1-form with one zero of multiplicity $2g-2$ in $P$ which can be decomposed in holomorphic and anti-holomorphic part. How can $H^1(R,P,\mathbb{C})$ have complex dimension $2g$ if every form in this group has the same holomorphic part up to a constant?

Comment: First of all, I believe you're wrong about the relative cohomology $H^1(R,P)$.